# GET method not working on specific route in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When I try to get data using `/:user` the function is not running inside the specific routing, can anyone figure me out what is the mistake here?

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const {accountSC,catalogSC} = require("./schema");

let dburl = **database url**
app.use(express.json());
mongoose.connect(dburl);

app.get("/catalog", async (req, res) => {
  //some func inside it
});

app.get("/:catalog/:id", async (req, res) => {
    //some func inside it
});

app.get("/:user", async (req, res) => {
    //some func inside it
});
```

Comment: what exactly is happening?

Comment: is it hitting the 2nd route when route 3 is called

Comment: It just responded with an empty JSON object @TheWhiteFang

Comment: yes it hits the 2nd route, how to fix it @cmgchess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your `/catalog` and `/:user` are the same because of the structure. `:user` value can be `catalog` also. So, try out different naming approaches of the routes (`/info/:user`).

Thank you.

update:
Try out this one.

```
app.get("/catalog", async (req, res) => {
  //some func inside it
});

app.get("/catalog/:catalog/:id", async (req, res) => {
    //some func inside it
});

app.get("/info/:user", async (req, res) => {
    //some func inside it
});
```

Comment: I even tried this approach too but not working

Comment: try out the updated one in the answer.

Comment: thank you it's working now, can please explain the concept behind this or share any resource for that

Comment: If you use the same name/pattern like `/catalog` and `/:user`, basically both are the same in a way that, `:user` can be anything(`/catalog`) right? same for the `/info/:user` and `/:catalog/:id` both are the same in a way that in the second one, `:catalog` can be anything (like `/info/`). That's why we always use some prefix or different params lengths if both are in the same method. In your case, it was the `get` method.

Comment: That's clear now, thank you for your explanation 

Comment: My pleasure, an upvote on the answer will be appreciated.